# Python-HTTP Version Not Supported

Tags: python-2.7

This is my first question on stackoverflow. im using it since 3 years for checking my errors and thankfully never neded to ask a question.

Im new to python. Im getting the error mentioned in the title when im requesting for a webpage.

> Python-HTTP Version Not Supported

Here is my code:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
req = Request(url)
try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except URLError as e:
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        print 'We failed to reach a server.'
        print 'Reason: ', e.reason
    elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
        print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
        print 'Error code: ', e.code
    else:
        print 'fine'
```

Comment: http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose?user=(username:password)&senderID=(SA)&receipientno=(DA)&msgtxt=(message) API&state=(1,2,3,4)

Comment: Ive not put the user id and password for security

Comment: does the same happen if you use requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/?

Comment: When you say "Im getting the error", you mean that the code snippet shown is printing out `Reason: Python-HTTP Version Not Supported`, that is that the `urlopen` line is throwing an exception with that reason? Or do you mean that you're getting that text in the response from the sever?

Comment: yes im getting the same error @PadraicCunningham